# What is the meaning of 'displaying' in Google Webmaster's Search Queries page?

Tags: google-search-console, click-tracking, impressions

What is the meaning of `displaying` in Google Webmaster Search Queries page?

[image]

I could not find the information in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35252?hl=en).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the total number of `Impressions` and `Clicks` currently being displayed for the `Query` terms in the table below your image, based on the selected date range, and with `Web` selected under `Filters`.

Comment: So it means webmaster does not show all the long-tail queries (for example). These impressions and clicks are included in the bold number. Ok, thanks.

Comment: The "Displaying" figure is the total being displayed, across all "pages" (in the pagination series) below the table. The "Show" pull-down just alters the pagination, nothing more. I certainly get some "long-tail queries" in the results. I would assume that those results that don't show fall below some minimum threshold.